# Order by in subquery and alias

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a problem with a order by in oracle query.

```
select KEY, B, C, (select D from TABLE1 a where a.KEY = b.KEY and a.DATE< 
b.DATE order BY a.DATE and rownum =1 ) 
FROMSTATUS from TABLE2 b
```

I known the "order by" is not working in subquery. I modify my query as:

```
select KEY, B, C, (select * from (select D from TABLE1 a where a.KEY = 
b.KEY and a.DATE< b.DATE order by DATE) where rownum = 1)
FROMSTATUS from TABLE2 b
```

But in this way the B.KEY and B.DATE has not resolved by oracle

I need select only a 1 value from TABLE2 and the value is the first previous a.DATE

Example:

```
 TABLE1
 KEY    DATE        A    B    C 
 1      01/31/2000  1    2    3
 2      02/25/2000  X    Y    Z   

 TABLE2
 KEY    DATE          D
 1      01/30/2000    1
 1      01/27/2000    2
 1      01/25/2000    2
 2      02/20/2000    4
 2      02/13/2000    1
```

I need this result:

```
TABLE1.KEY   TABLE1.DATE    TABLE1.A TABLE1.B TABLE1.C TABLE2.DATE TABLE2.D
1            01/31/2000     1        2        3        01/30/2000  1
2            02/25/2000     X        Y        Z        02/20/2000  4
```

Can you help me?

(i am sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Skip the sub-query, do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: The queries don't match your description. You've mixed table1 and table2 up. You've also applied the wrong order, it would have to be `order by date desc` to get the highest date first.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you have reason, i have correct my question

Answer (score 1):

`row_number()` after `union` will get your output.

```
 select tFinal.DATE, tFinal.KEY 
 from (select row_number() over (partition by KEY order by t1.T, t1.DATE desc) as rn, t1.DATE, t1.KEY 
        from 
        (select DATE, KEY, 't1' as T from TABLE1
        union all
        select DATE, KEY, 't2' as T from TABLE2) t1) tFinal
 Where rn = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TABLE2.KEY, TABLE2.B, TABLE2.C, TABLE1.D
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE2.KEY, TABLE2.DATE ORDER BY TABLE1.DATE DESC) AS rn
    FROM TABLE2
    LEFT JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE2.KEY = TABLE1.KEY AND TABLE2.DATE > TABLE1.DATE
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that uses aggregation:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 KEY, to_date('31/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 KEY, to_date('25/02/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 1 KEY, to_date('30/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 KEY, to_date('27/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 KEY, to_date('25/01/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 KEY, to_date('20/02/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 KEY, to_date('13/02/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt FROM dual)
SELECT t1.KEY,
       t1.dt t1_date,
       MAX(t2.dt) t2_date
FROM   t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.key = t2.key AND t2.dt < t1.dt
GROUP BY t1.key, t1.dt
ORDER BY t1.key;

       KEY T1_DATE     T2_DATE
---------- ----------- -----------
         1 31/01/2000  30/01/2000
         2 25/02/2000  20/02/2000
```

I'm assuming here that t1.key is a unique column. Whether this is more performant than any of the other answers for your data is up to you to test *{:-)

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can use `KEEP LAST` for this:

```
select
  key,
  b,
  c,
  (
    select max(d) keep (dense_rank last order by t2.date)
    from table2 t2
    where t2.key = t1.key and t2.date < t1.date
  ) as fromstatus
from table1 t1;
```

As of Oracle 12c you can also use `FETCH FIRST ROW`:

```
select
  key,
  b,
  c,
  (
    select d
    from table2 t2
    where t2.key = t1.key and t2.date < t1.date
    order by t2.date desc
    fetch first row only
  ) as fromstatus
from table1 t1;
```

or, moving the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
select
  t1.key,
  t1.b,
  t1.c,
  first_t2.d as fromstatus
from table1 t1
outer apply
(
  select d
  from table2 t2
  where t2.key = t1.key and t2.date < t1.date
  order by t2.date desc
  fetch first row only
) first_t2;
```

This last query has the advantage that you could easily select more values from the table2 row than just one.